# Godot: How to run export to GLTF tool from script in game?

Tags: godot

Hello everyone I am creating a game on the Godot engine.

I need to generate a mesh from scene and save it to a file when the game is running.

I'm trying to use Godot Project/Tools/Export_GLTF in the script, but I don't find any possibilities for this.

Can anyone help me with this? Is it possible to use the built-in Godot tool in the script or do I need to write objmaker myself?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to use Godot Project/Tools/Export_GLTF in the script, but I don't find any possibilities for this.

You cannot access that function from scripting. However, right now in Godot 3.4+ you can do this in a [`tool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/running_code_in_the_editor.html) script:

```
    var gltf := PackedSceneGLTF.new()
    var err := gltf.export_gltf(self, "res://scene.gltf")
    if err != OK:
        print("error: " + str(err))
```

---

> I need to generate a mesh from scene and save it to a file when the game is running.

I reiterate that you can do what I said above from the editor (in a `tool` script), not from the game. This is because the necessary GLTF related classes are excluded from the game builds of Godot (i.e. the export templates). So you would need to make a custom build of Godot to have this functionality in your game.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's works for me. I  I have run  mesh generating script on dedicate linux server. This PackedSceneGLTF work in game if you use export custom template with enabled editor tools.